# Check for duplicates in an array of objects in Golang with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I need to find duplicate entries of a specific value in an array of objects in a Mongo database. My structure looks something like this:

```
type gameTemplate struct {
ID       bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
GameCode string        `bson:"gamecode" json:"gamecode"`
Players  []player      `bson:"players" json:"players"`
}

type player struct {
PlayerID bson.ObjectId `bson:"playerid" json:"playerid"`
Username string        `bson:"username" json:"username"`
}
```

If a new player is joining the game, I want to check to make sure their username is not taken. I used this method for checking for duplicate game codes (if `count` is greater than 1, I know there's a game that exists):

```
count, err := collection.Find(bson.M{"gamecode": entry.GameCode}).Limit(1).Count()
```

Which works well, but obviously won't work to check the `username` value of an object in the array of players. I am thinking I would have to do something along the lines of checking the size of the array and iterating through each option to find a duplicate, but I haven't had any sort of success.

**EDIT**

I am running the latest version of MongoDB and am using the mgo.v2 driver for go. The flow of what I am trying to achieve looks something like this:

> Player Y wants to join game X. Game X can only have a single instance of a 'username', but that same username can be present in other games.

Comment: Hi @CarsonS5, which MongoDB Go driver are you using ? Also, which MongoDB version are you using ? You can try to use [$elemMatch: array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents) to query.

Comment: @WanBachtiar I am using the mgo.v2 driver with the latest version of MongoDB installed. I've looked at the link you've provided, but I want to check just within a specific document. So, if player Y wants to join game X check game X for any other entries of player Y's username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents)

```
collection.Find(bson.M{"gamecode": entry.GameCode},bson.M{"players": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"playerid": playerid}}}).Limit(1).Count()
```

Comment: That is what I have tried to do, however I want to search a specific document in the DB, not all of them. 

So I want to find if there is another player with the same username in a specific game.

Comment: check my edited answer, Now you can find a particular game and player is already exists or not.